# Is it Ελλάδα or is it Geometry

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction

Here’s the riddle:

If taled is a triangle, ip looks like a table, and ix is ( I ) sideways, what is amoge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This riddle is describing

> letters in the Greek alphabet. Omega is Ω,

Meaning an answer, given that we're describing looks, could be:

> A hood, hair, a weird circle, etc.!

Comment: Was it too obvious?

Comment: Yes, the riddle was easy enough as it is, but the title also gave it away.

Comment: Oh, should I have picked a different language to put Greek in?